# Custom aggregation with WSO2EI and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, jongo

I'm tring to implement aggregation operations for Mongo data service in WSO2DSS (in WSO2EI) since only the basic operations like CRUD and Count are supported out of the box as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060370/wso2-dss-support-for-mongodb-3-x-x). So I cloned [WSO2EI code version 4.4.10](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-data/tree/v4.4.10)  (our team happens to be using this version) and I've successfully added some of my own functionality. However, whenever I try to use `org.jongo.MongoCollection.aggregate()` function, I get error `Error in MongoQuery.runQuery: Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument'`. I checked all the posts regarding this issue and tried to use different versions of Mongo driver (3.4, 3.6..), also changed the actual syntax a lot but no matter what I try, I always get this error if I use the `.aggregate()` function. Also should I be using `org.jongo.MongoCollection.aggregate(String pipelineOperator)` or  `com.mongodb.async.client.aggregate(java.util.List<? extends Bson> pipeline)` as stated in the Mongo Java 3.6 documentation [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#aggregate-java.util.List-). Example code I used:

```
private Iterator<MongoTestClass> doAggregate1(MongoCollection collection, String opQuery, Object[] parameters) throws DataServiceFault {

        return collection.aggregate("{$match:{componentType:'Endpoint'}}")
                .as(MongoTestClass.class).iterator();

    }
```

where `componentType` is existing field in my MongoDB collection document and `'Endpoint'` is it's value. Is my actual synatax wrong? Or is there any other problem? How can I add the `'cursor'` to my query so the error goes away?

I can't wrap my head around how this works...much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs.

> MongoDB 3.4 deprecates the use of aggregate command without the cursor
>   option, unless the pipeline includes the explain option. When
>   returning aggregation results inline using the aggregate command,
>   specify the cursor option using the default batch size cursor: {} or
>   specify the batch size in the cursor option cursor: { batchSize: 
>   }.

You can pass `batchSize` with `AggregationOptions` for Jongo Aggregate method.

```
AggregationOptions options = AggregationOptions.builder().options.
     batchSize(100).
     outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.CURSOR).build();

collection.aggregate("{$match:{componentType:'Endpoint'}}").options(options).as(MongoTestClass.class).iterator();
```

With default batch size

```
AggregationOptions options = AggregationOptions.builder().options.
     outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.CURSOR).build();
```

OR

```
AggregationOptions options = AggregationOptions.builder().build();

collection.aggregate("{$match:{componentType:'Endpoint'}}").options(options).as(MongoTestClass.class).iterator();
```